# Is there a way to monitor response codes and response bodies in Log Explorer in GTM Server-Side project in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-tag-manager-server-side

I need to setup some sort of alert system when something in my GTM Server-Side implementation goes wrong (namely, if some of the requests are malformed and the endpoints comes back with an error code).

When in the debug view, I can see responses quite easily:

[image]

But I have hard time finding this information in Log Explorer in Google Cloud. I can see the requests themselves though

[image]

But it looks like the response body isn't available.

Is there a way to make this happen so I can continuously monitor that all my tags are working properly?

Answer (score 0):

These are response codes of google's collect endpoint. Why would you want to track that and how if they don't get in? We typically do that kind of analysis differently. We set up custom alerts in GA to be alerted whenever anything atypical happens. In this case, the rule would be simple: just the drop of general traffic over what's a reasonable historical fluctuation. [Here's](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9443595?hl=en) more on it.

There's much more sense in tracking response codes of your site, to see when people get errors browsing, but that's typically done by just tagging the error pages that webserver is meant to return for the error responses. That is, if you supplement your server-side GTM with the front-end tracking. Otherwise, it's up to the backend developers to wire it in to you.